# Attempting to loop through data returned by API and append each task to an unordered list

Tags: jquery, json

As the title describes. I have attached clips of current code and what the function is outputting. I am new to javascript so any sort of detailed explanation woudld be incredibly helpful! Thank you!

Edit: apparently code lines got cut off. Get request is like 80, loop starts on 83 for reference.

Edit 2: Hhere is the code:

```
function add_task(){

    var the_serialized_data = $('#frm_todo').serialize();

    console.log(the_serialized_data);

    $.post('http://misdemo.hidden.edu/todo/addtask/', the_serialized_data, function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $('#confirmation').html("Task added okay.")
    });

}; //end add task

function get_tasks(){
//iterate through the tasks and add those for tuid to line 42
    var the_serialized_data = $('#frm_todo').serialize();
    console.log(the_serialized_data);


    $.get('http://misdemo.hidden.edu/todo/tasks/', the_serialized_data, function(data){
        console.log(data)

        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var obj = data[i]

            $('#tasklist').append(obj)
        };
    });

}; //end get tasks
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kq3M.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCjAx.png)

Comment: Post the code here, not screenshots

Comment: `data[i]` has many keys, which ones do you need to show? You cannot directly append, you need to wrap text around `<li>` tags

Comment: i just need to show whatever the user inputs for example "eat", "sleep" or "drink" and append those to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `#tasklist` is a `<ul>`, your loop would be :

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var obj = data[i]
    $('#tasklist').append("<li>" + obj.task + "</li>")
}
```